# Convert decimal to hour and minute

Tags: .net, vb.net, type-conversion

I want to get hours and minutes from a Decimal value.

Example: Decimal value is 12.50. So, the value will be 12 hours and 30 minutes.

How can I get this with shortest way?

Comment: have you tried anything? check `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} hours and {1} minutes", CInt(12.5), (12.5 Mod 1) * 60))`

Comment: I got it with your way. Thanks.

Comment: caution: `12.51` will give you `12 hours 30.6 minutes` use `CInt()` or `Round()` if you don't want decimal minutes.

Comment: BTW,what's your _time format_?

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should work too

```
Dim ts = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 12.5 * 60, 0)
```

Comment: `Dim tim As Decimal = 120.5`
        `Dim ts = New TimeSpan(0, 0, tim * 60, 0)`

Comment: Easier would be to use Dim ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(12.5)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Dim val as Decimal = 12.50

hours = Convert.ToInt32(val)
minutes = (val Mod hours) * 60
```

Comment: `minutes = (val Mod 1) * 60` also has the same effect